# Enable div scroll for a particular section jquery fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am using jquery fullpage.js. And i need  scrollbar for last div on my page. I have 4 sections. For first 3 sections i need autoScrolling true and for last section autoScrolling false. Is there any option to set this in fullpage.js?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose you have 4 block like these right.
you have need to scroll bar in the last section Ok.
So we can make with the help of CSS and JQuery both.

Using CSS

```
<style>
.sec_4{
height:100px;
width:200px
background:#000;
color:#fff;
overflow:auto;
}
</style>
```

Using JQuery
use JQuery library file first.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sec_4').css({
        'overflow': 'auto',
        'width': '200px',
        'height': '100px',
        'background': '#000',
        'color': '#fff'
    })
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="sec_1">
</div>

<div class="sec_2">
</div>

<div class="sec_3">
</div>

<div class="sec_4">
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working. Is there any way to add next button arrow?

Comment: Again, this won't work properly. Whenever you scroll up in the latest section, it will fire the fullpage.js scrolling and you will be moved to the section above. Even if you are in the bottom of your last section trying to scroll inside it.

Comment: This is not the solution to your problem. @Websolutionexpert24 has clearly not tested it in fullpage.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `overflowScroll:true` for that case. That will create an scrolling bar whenever it is needed if the content is bigger than the view port height.

Take a look at [this demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

Comment: But this option is not working i have more content in my last section and there is no scrollbar coming after adding this option.

Comment: That's probably because you are forgetting something... You can see how it works properly in the example I provided. Check if you are including the slimScroll javascript file after fullpage.js.